# SQLite Date type Error when querying a database for a website

Tags: python, sqlite, date, datetime

I have been stuck on this error for the longest and it is getting very annoying. I've checked my code countless times and like I said I'm annoyed as to why this SQLAlchemy error is coming up.

What am I doing: I'm trying to send data to a Database in the format as a Date time i.e. "MM/DD/YYYY" through the use of a user input. When implemented the code seems to work fine until I ask to "save" the date to the Database.

```
class Task(db.Model):

__tablename__ = "tasks"

    task_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    due_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    priority = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    posted_date = db.Column(db.Date, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    status = db.Column(db.Integer)

def __init__(self, name, due_date, priority, status, user_id, posted_date):
    self.name = name
    self.due_date= due_date
    self.priority= priority
    self.status= status
    self.posted_date = posted_date  
    self.user_id = user_id

def __repr__(self):
    return '<name[0]>'.format(self.name)
```

The above piece of script is the model of a Task

```
    from views import db
    from config import DATABASE_PATH

    import sqlite3
    from datetime import datetime

   with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        c = connection.cursor()

        c.execute("""ALTER TABLE tasks RENAME TO old_tasks""")

        db.create_all()

        c.execute("""SELECT name, due_date, priority,
            status FROM old_tasks ORDER BY task_id ASC""")

        data = [(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3],
            datetime.now(), 1) for row in c.fetchall()]

   c.executemany("""INSERT INTO tasks (name, due_date, priority, status,
                       posted_date, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", data)

        c.execute("DROP TABLE old_tasks")
```

The above script drops an existing database that I have and rewrites it with the above credentials.

```
    @app.route('/add/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def new_task():
        form = AddTaskForm(request.form)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                new_task = Task(
                    form.name.data,
                    form.due_date.data,
                    form.priority.data,
                    datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                    '1',
                    session['user_id']
                )
                db.session.add(new_task)
                db.session.commit()
                flash('New entry was successfully posted. Thanks!')
                return redirect(url_for('tasks'))
            else: 
                flash("Please put all credentials Necessary")
                return redirect(url_for('tasks'))
        return render_template('tasks.html', form=form)
```

The above script comes from my views.py script and serves as the algorithm behind saving a task with required credentials.

The annoying Error I'm receiving happens to be this:

> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite Date type
>   only accepts Python date objects as input. [SQL: 'INSERT INTO tasks
>   (name, due_date, priority, user_id, posted_date, status) VALUES (?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: [{'status': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 1,
>   5, 24, 48, 23300), 'priority': '6', 'posted_date': 1, 'due_date':
>   datetime.date(2017, 5, 17), 'name': 'lol', 'user_id': '1'}]]

I know that there are questions answered about this but this question is much more specific than the latter. If you can help please reply! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are passing the `user_id` from the form as the `posted_date` in the `Task` constructor

**Creating a new task from your view**

```
new_task = Task(
                form.name.data,
                form.due_date.data,
                form.priority.data,
                datetime.datetime.utcnow(), #this should probably be at the end
                '1',
                session['user_id'] #check this here
            )
```

**Task constructor**

```
def __init__(self, name, due_date, priority, status, user_id, posted_date): #posted date is the last param
    self.name = name
    self.due_date= due_date
    self.priority= priority
    self.status= status
    self.posted_date = posted_date  
    self.user_id = user_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't see that I passed the wrong parameter! No wonder! The parameter 'user_id' is not input-able data! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)